# VcProj or VcxProj Build Include Tag Question

Tags: include

i would like to edit the vcproj to include some additional header, additional dependecy and lib file.

What is the correct tag ?

Any script that generate this vcproj file ?

My vcproj has this Environment="PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin;$(PATH)"

and my settings has this

Additional Include Directory
.\GeneratedFiles
$(QTDIR)\include
.\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)
$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore
C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_40_0\boost_1_40_0\boost
C:\Program Files\VOIP\pjproject-1.4\pjproject-1.4\pjmedia\include\

Additional Library Directory
C:\Program Files\VOIP\pjproject-1.4\pjproject-1.4\lib
$(QTDIR)\lib

Additional Dependecies
qtmain.lib
QtCore4.lib
QtGui4.lib
QtXml4.lib
QtSql4.lib
QtOpenGL4.lib
opengl32.lib

I did not saw some setting in vcproj such as

These two was not set in vcproj.
C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_40_0\boost_1_40_0\boost
C:\Program Files\VOIP\pjproject-1.4\pjproject-1.4\pjmedia\include\

QTDIR and PATH was declared as environment variable.

[code]

[/code]

Please help.

Thanks.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2208a1f2(VS.71).aspx